Finite groups with no $ A_5 $ subgroup
The smallest nonsolvable group is $ A_5 $.
What can we say about a finite group with no $ A_5 $ subgroup? Certainly all solvable groups have this property. What about nonsolvable finite groups with no $ A_5 $ subgroup? Do they have any interesting or notable properties?
Motivation: The motivation for this is that in the theory of quantum error correcting codes it is know that the transversal gate group $ G $ of a stabilizer code is always a finite group and moreover cannot contain an $ A_5 $ subgroup (other restrictions are also known, such as the fact that $ G $ must contain a certain central product with an extraspecial $ 2 $ group, known as the $ n $ qubit Pauli group). It is an interesting question to study which groups can occur as the transversal gate group of a stabilizer code.
Update: Such groups are not necessarily solvable, for example the simple group $ SL(3,2) $ of order $ 168 $ has no $ A_5 $ subgroup and is not solvable. And, more relevant for the case I describe, two blocks of the Steane code is a stabilizer code with transversal gate group called "two qubit Clifford group" which is isomorphic to the complex reflection group with Shephard Todd number 31 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_reflection_group. The 2 qubit Clifford group is definitely not solvable, indeed it has an index 2 commutator subgroup which is a perfect group of order 23040, in particular in GAP notation this commutator subgroup is isomorphic to PerfectGroup(23040,1).

Don't know but a solvable group might well be necessary.   Possibly ask here:
https://cs.stackexchange.com/

@softtostadaburrito solvable is not necessary, see update.

I believe that this mathoverflow post answers the title question affirmatively, so that a finite simple group contains a copy of $A_5$ if and only if its order is divisible by $60$, except perhaps for a few exceptional groups.

(Clarify: "title question" is the question on the title ofvthe linked MO post)

@ArturoMagidin that is definitely interesting
